# Changing the css of button when its active

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to change the CSS for the element btn1 (its a button) while its active.
I want to look different as long as "story" is shown (when pressed shows a div, as long as the div is shown i want the button to have a different color from the normal css)

```
$(function() {
    $('#btn1').on('click', function() {
        $('#story').fadeToggle(400);
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Just use the css selector, `:active`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) method:

```
$('#btn1').on('click', function() {
    $(this).css({'border':'1px solid blue', 'color':'red'});
    $('#story').fadeToggle(400);
});
```

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/35Xkf/2/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#btn1').on('click', function() {
 $(this).toggleClass('active'); // add/remove a css class
 $('#story').fadeToggle(400);
});
```

in your css add

```
.active{
// styles you wish to apply
}
```

Comment: doesent work, it is possible to add the css in the jquery , for example like :  
$("btn1").css({color:'red'})

Comment: @Iulian Alexandru: You missed the id selector. "$("#btn1").css({color:'red'})". Check Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/35Xkf/1/

Answer (score 0):

`:active` selector [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3aactive)

and look on this site http://www.paulund.co.uk/css3-buttons-with-pseudo-classes

Comment: not when its clicked, when its active(when pressed shows a div, as long as the div is shown i want the button to have a different color from the normal css )

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to do this:

```
$(function() {
    $('#btn1').on('click', function() {
        $(this).css('background-color','red'); // or whatever
        $('#story').fadeToggle(400, function() { // 'complete' callback function
            $('#btn1').css('background-color','white');
        });
    }); 
});
```